# How can I compress BLOB data in sqlite database in order to reduce its size?

Tags: php, sqlite, imagemagick, size, blob

I have an sqlite database that contains **BLOB data.**

Each BLOB field contains an **image.**

(Specifically this database was created by Maperitive, a tool that generates
[mbtiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MBTiles))

I would like to **reduce the size of each BLOB field**, in order to reduce the size of the sqlite database.

What I've done till now is:

I have created a PHP script that

- 1) reads the BLOB fields,converts them to images (.jpgs) and stores the images in a new directory named 'BLOB2IMAGES'.

  ```
   <?php      
        file_put_contents("./BLOB2IMAGES/". $currentImage, $BLOB_DATA);
   ?>
  ```
- 2) Afterwards, I use an external tool named
  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). This tool has several commands in order to modify an image. I use the **mogrify command** that **overwrittes** the
  images by modifying the quality of the images.

  In that case the size 
  of the images is reduced

  ```
    mogrify -format jpg -quality 75% -path "C:\BLOB2IMAGES" "C:\BLOB2IMAGES\*.jpg"
  ```
- 3) Then I have a created a second PHP script that reads the
  **BLOB2IMAGES directory**, converts each compressed image to a byte array and stores
  the byte array in the sqlite database. (**Attention**:I have created 
  a new sqlite database in order to store the 'new' BLOB data with the reduced size).

  ```
   <?php
        $byte_array_of_Compressed_image =file_get_contents(("./BLOB2IMAGES/". $compressedImage);
   ?>
  ```

I noticed that in the **1st  conversion of the BLOB data to images** (.jpgs) the quality of the produced images  is not so good and I don't like that. Then I created a simple JAVA program, that converts the BLOB data to  images and again I noticed thet the quality was not so good.

Generally, I would like to reduce the size of the BLOB data, so I followed the previous steps.
Is there any other way in order to reduce the size of the BLOB data?
Any tool or any additional extension?
Shall I use a different approach than the one I have already used?

I would be glad if you could give me solutions or ideas related to my problem.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: The JPEG quality parameter lets you trade off quality against size. Try other values. Why don't you use PNG?

Comment: Cause PNG increases the size of the sqlite database.

Comment: @CL. what is your opinion, shall I create PNG images and then compress them instead of compressing .jpgs? Is there any other solution for reducing the size  of BLOB fields?

Comment: You should be able to shrink PNG files by reducing the color depth to 8 bits and doing other changes with some [optimizing tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OptiPNG#Optimizing_tools).